# undefined reference to `nppiMalloc_8u_C1'

Tags: reference, undefined, gpu, nvcc, npp

I am trying to run a program on Ubuntu 16.04 using npp library. 
In order to link library and the program, I wrote this command on terminal :

```
nvcc -L/home/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib  main.cu
```

However, this error occurs :

```
/tmp/tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-10_main.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `nppiMalloc_8u_C1'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `nppiMalloc_8u_C1'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `nppiMinMaxGetBufferHostSize_8u_C1R'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `nppiMinMax_8u_C1R'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `nppiSubC_8u_C1RSfs'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to `nppiMulC_8u_C1IRSfs'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `nppiFree'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `nppiFree'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `nppiFree'
tmpxft_000048ee_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to `nppiFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did not find anything on the internet and I am new at *gpu programming*.

Is there an idea how I can fix the problem please?

Answer (score 1):

`nvcc` links only `cudart` library by default. If you want to use any other library included with the toolkit such as `NPP`, you have to link its relevant libraries explicitely as follows:

> nvcc -L/home/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib  main.cu
>   -lnppc -lnppi -lnppial